# Reserving space for variables and activation record

Tags: c++, c, memory, stack

Does only declaring a variable reserves a space for it in the program memory? And if not, then please consider the following snippet:

```
void foo(int bar, int baz){
int a;
char b[4];
}
```

This code as soon as it enters foo allocates a space in stack and creates an activation record like this:

---

### |   baz    |

---

### |   bar    |

---

### | saved PC |

---

### |    a     |

---

### |    b     |

So, how does this activation record allocates space for a and b even if they are only declared and not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are defined but not used. Since the program can't tell whether they were created, the compiler is free to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, under some optimization condition compiler may choose to discard space taken by uninitialized variables.However it is always suggested to remove never used variables from your code.

Under general condition, suppose 32 bit system,your compiler will evacuate a minimum of 4+4 bytes of space in the stack for saving data of variables which may be used in future.

Comment: So, this means that space is not reserved when the variable is declared right and is allocated when it is defined instead? Am I getting this right?

Comment: no mostly it is reserved so you may get warning of uninitialized variable